# Não consigo invocar um setter ou getter no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, método, getters-setters

Estava fazendo alguns exercícios de orientação a objetos e na solução o professor usou `set` e `get`. Percebi que mesmo fazendo como o professor,  não funciona. Consigo resolver sem `get` e `set`, mas queria saber como usá-los em JavaScript.

```
class Endereco{
  constructor(rua) {
    this.rua = rua;
  }

  set novaRua(nova){
    this.rua = nova;
  }

let E1 = new Endereco(null);
E1.novaRua("rua x");
console.log(E1.rua);
```

A saída:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: E1.novaRua is not a function
>   at aula8.js:77
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando você usa os assessores [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) ou [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) em JavaScript, ele utiliza o formato de acesso ou definição padrão da linguagem.

Então, para acessar, você deve utilizar:

```
obj.prop;
```

E para definir:

```
obj.prop = "New Value";
```

Veja um exemplo:

```js
class Person {
  name = undefined;
  
  set name(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  get name() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

const p = new Person();
console.log(p.name); // undefined
p.name = 'Luiz';
console.log(p.name); // Luiz
```

Note que esses assessores não são exclusivos de classes. Você também pode utilizá-los em objetos literais.

Answer (score 4):

Faltou uma chave `{` para completar a sintaxe de declaração de classe e houve um equivoco na sua interpretação do [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set).

O setter liga uma propriedade do objeto a uma função a ser chamada quando houver uma tentativa de definir essa propriedade.
Em JavaScript, um setter pode ser usado para executar uma função sempre que uma propriedade especificada for alterada. Setters são usados com mais frequência em conjunto com getters para criar um tipo de pseudo-propriedade.

```js
class Endereco {
  constructor(rua) {
    this.rua = rua;
  }

  set novaRua(nova) {
    this.rua = nova;
  }
} //<-- Estava faltando essa chave

let E1 = new Endereco(null);
E1.novaRua = "rua x"; //<-- Apenas defina o valor da propriedade.
console.log(E1.rua);
```

Comment: Acho que só faltou o fechamento das chaves quando ele foi transcrever o código para a pergunta, caso contrário o erro que ele fosse receber seria `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`, já que ele nem conseguiria tentar invocar (incorretamente) o _setter_, já que o _parser_ teria falhado antes. :-)

Comment: @LuizFelipe, provavelmente sim, mas eu já resolvi um problema que o foi gerado na transcrição da pergunta.